# Android studio Viewport scale landscape mode does not work, webview

Tags: android, webview, scale, landscape, portrait

I have the code for a webview application and the scaling is different for the landscape and portrait mode.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In fact, it seems that no matter what I change the scale to, it has no effect in Landscape mode.
It does work in portrait mode.
Why is this and how to fix?

Also, Is there a way to conditionally set the scale based on portrait or landscape?

Comment: do you use `webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`

Comment: yes.. it is/was there.. and.. all of a sudden it is working.. not sure what is happening.. thanks.. I guess I should delete the question.  But I'll see if the problem comes again.  your response is appreciated.. i'm not really an android programmer and just trying to make a webpage into webview app.  (which is working and published).